# Is it possible to input values for confidence interval/ error bars on seaborn barplot?

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I'm used to doing my barplots on seaborn and I like it's layout for showing confidence bars, but I have a special case in a dataset where I already have the confidence interval, like this:

```
month   ci-b     mean    ci-t
201801  0.020   0.0206  0.021
201802  0.019   0.0198  0.0204
201803  0.022   0.0225  0.0228
201804  0.022   0.0236  0.0240
201805  0.023   0.0235  0.0239
```

Is there a way to manually input the values for seaborn confidence interval lines? Or to use it as "None" and use some matlib function to put the confidence interval in the graph (but keeping seaborn's barplot)

When I do:

```
ax = sns.barplot('month','mean',data=df, ci=None)
```

I get, as expected, a normal barplot:

[image: This graphic]

And when I attempt to use matlib's error bar like this:

```
ax = sns.barplot('month','mean',data=df, ci=None)
plt.errorbar(x=df['month'],y=df['mean'],yerr=(df['ci-t']-df['ci-b']))
```

Everything get's messed up with just one strange line lost in the figure:

[image: Like this graphic]

Am I using errorbar wrong? Is there a better tool for this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Update** (August 2, 2019):

My earlier answer (see below) overstates the error because `yerr` uses the same error for the top and bottom if passed a single array of shape (N,). To get different errors for the bottom and top, we need to use an array of shape (2, N). The first row is used for the bottom error and the second for the top (from [the documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.errorbar.html). In code this is:

```py
# Bottom error, then top
yerr = [df['mean']-df['ci-b'], df['ci-t'] - df['mean']]

ax = sns.barplot('month','mean',data=df, ci=None)
plt.errorbar(x=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],y=df['mean'],
            yerr=yerr, fmt='none', c= 'r')
```

The result is below:
[image]

The errors are now different on the bottom and top.

Following is a direct comparison, with the original (symmetrical) error bars in red and the non-symmetrical error bars in blue. We can directly see the differences:

[image]

**Earlier Answer with Exaggerated Errors**

The months are being interpreted differently by `seaborn` and `matplotlib`resulting in odd placement of the error bars. You also need to specify `fmt='none'` to avoid having `errorbar` plot data points as a line. The following code places the errors bars at the correct x locations:

```
ax = sns.barplot('month','mean',data=df, ci=None)
plt.errorbar(x=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],y=df['mean'],
             yerr=(df['ci-t']-df['ci-b']), fmt='none', c= 'r')
```

[image]

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, I think this method is overrepresenting (maybing doubling) the size of the error bars. Look at the 4th column, 201804. The upper bound in the figure seems to be at or above .025, whereas in OP's table, the upper bound is only .024?

Comment: Yes, I think you may be correct since `plt.errorbar` adds and subtracts the same error on both sides when passed a 1-dimensional array of values. [Here is the documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.errorbar.html).

Comment: To correct for this, it looks like we need to pass a `(2, N)` array of values to `yerr` with the negative in the first row followed by the positive errors. So the call would be something like: `yerr=[df['ci-mean']-df['ci-b'], df['ci-t'] - df['ci-mean']]` 
I think that's the correct interpretation of the documentation. With the original answer, the same error is added and subtracted. This is not correct because the error is derived from the top - bottom when in reality, there are separate errors.

Comment: I corrected my answer in response to your comment. I think the errors should be correct now, but more feedback is appreciated.

Comment: I think that's right, but you might want to put the corrected code on top, just in case other folks just blindly take the first part of your answer. :-)

Comment: Done! Thanks for looking over this carefully. I would have been ignorant of my error if you hadn't pointed it out!